# textbox in the radiobutton doesn't work

Tags: c#, html

here is my code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="PlaceofWork" name="PlaceofWork" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

code behind:

```
 PlaceofWork.DataSource = workplace;
 PlaceofWork.DataBind();
 PlaceofWork.Items.Add(new ListItem("Other - Specify<input name=\"OtherWorkPlace\" type=\"text\" id=\"OtherWorkPlace\" MaxLength=\"25\"/>", "19"));
```

And for some reason, I have another radiobuttonlist which have to add items manually, code is like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="DPC23" GroupName="Responsibility" class="Responsibility" runat="server" Text="PeriAnesthesia/RR" value="26" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="DPC24" GroupName="Responsibility" class="Responsibility" runat="server" Text="Other&ndash;Specify <input id='OtherDPC' type='text' MaxLength='25'/>" value="19" />
```

Now the problem is when the code run in chrome, everything is ok, but when it is opened in IE, the textbox in PlaceofWork doesn't work, when I click the textbox, it will lose the cursor, but the manually added radiobutton works fine, does any one know why this happen??

Comment: what version of ie are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is a known incompatibility between ie10 and asp.net webforms. Check [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) out.

Comment: **The bug is not in IE 10, it's in WebForms.** The linked blog post confirms this.

Comment: actually, I downloaded the hotfix and installed, doesn't work